# Using Regex to encompass a group of keys in a dictionary and match them inside of a list of strings

Tags: python, text, nlp, data-cleaning, regexp-replace

I'm new to text-cleaning in python but I currently created a dictionary with various slang words/acronyms/contractions that looks something like this:

> fulltext = {'BYOB': 'bring your own beer', 'couldn't': 'could not', 'finna': 'going to'}... etc.

and I have another large corpus of text data:

> uncleaned_text = ['This is finna be crazy', 'I don't know why we couldn't be there', 'I should have known when the event was BYOB that it would be terrible']

For which I am trying to 'clean' by replacing those words inside the list of strings that match the dictionary keys with their corresponding values. So, my ideal output would be:

> cleaned text = ['This is going to be crazy', 'I don't know why we could not be there', 'I should have known when the event was bring your own beer that it would be terrible']

I know I should be using  REGEX in some way and I know I should be using loops, but I am definitely not even close to what I should be doing I think, because the error I get is builtin function not iterable...

Any suggestions?

for sentence in uncleaned_text:
for word in sentence:
if word in fulltext.keys:
word.replace(word, fulltext.key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are receiving is because `dictionary.keys` is a function not a list. So to get all the keys, you would want to use `fulltext.keys()` not `fulltext.keys`. The keys member of the dictionary class is a function that returns a list of the keys. The more pythonic way of checking if a specific word exists in the dictionary's keys is: `if key in dictionary`. The `in` operator checks to see if the left operand is a key in the dictionary, so you don't have to use the `.keys` function.

For the rest of the function I'd do the following:

```
clean_text = []
for sentence in uncleaned_text:
  for word in sentence.split():
    if word in fulltext: 
      sentence = sentence.replace(word, fulltext[word])
  clean_text.append(sentence)
```

The changes I made explained:

1. you'll need to split the sentence into words. The sentence is just a long string, so if you iterate over it you would get every character of the sentence individually. The .split method splits it on every space by default.
2. The replace method doesn't change the string in place, so you have to catch it in some other variable.
3. To get a value out of the dictionary, you'll need to use the key. Word is our key in this case, so I changed `fulltext.key` to be `fulltext[word]`. This gets the value associated with `word` from the fulltext dictionary.
4. Added an array to append the changed sentences to.

This will leave the original list (`uncleaned_text`) unchanged.

Comment: Thank you this makes a lot of sense!! I didn't realize I could use "in" for strings as well (for some reason only thought it was integers) so I will absolutely be adding this to my toolbelt.

Comment: Yep! It's super useful. If you found one of the answers helpful, would you mind accepting it? This helps everyone because users will not see this question as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful:

```
import re

fulltext = {"BYOB": "bring your own beer", "couldn't": "could not", "finna": "going to"}
uncleaned_text = ["This is finna be crazy", "I don't know why we couldn't be there", "I should have known when the event was BYOB that it would be terrible"]
cleaned_text = []
keys = fulltext.keys()
for text in uncleaned_text:
    for key in keys:
        if key in text:
            cleaned_text.append(re.sub(key,fulltext[key],text))
print("cleaned_text => ",cleaned_text)
```

However, this code will take a long time to run if you have lots of data because of the nested for-loop.

Comment: Thank you! This is absolutely helpful.